# Combine re flags re.IGNORECASE, re.MULTILINE and re.DOTALL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

Can anyone tell me if I can combine flags like `re.IGNORECASE`, `re.MULTILINE` and `re.DOTALL` for regular expression matching?

```
r = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

I need to match an entire paragraph or an expression in one line according to the use case.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile — "The expression’s behaviour can be modified by specifying a flags value. Values can be any of the following variables, combined using bitwise OR (the `|` operator)"

Comment: I am using it, but still find an issue seems not interpreted

Comment: i used it like this:                   
r = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL )
matches = list(r.finditer(log))

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can combine regex flags with `|`.

The documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile specifically says:

> The expression’s behaviour can be modified by specifying a *flags* value. Values can be any of the following variables, combined using bitwise OR (the `|` operator).